# How to use the ApplicationContext to set MidParent value using C#

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010, telerik, applicationcontext

I need to create a method that will open up a Mid form under some conditions. When opening the Mid form, I have to assign the `MidParent` value to the parent of the application.

I am trying to use the `ApplicationContext` class to figure out the current `MainForm` value, but it is not working as expected when it is called from a different Mid form.

Here is what I have done. In the `Program.cs` file Here is what I have

```
namespace RM
{
    static class Program
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// The main entry point for the application.
        /// </summary>
        private static AppContext aContext;
        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            aContext = new AppContext(new Main());

            Application.Run(aContext);
        }


        public static void Quit() {

            DialogResult res =
            MessageBox.Show("Are You Sure you want to close the application", "Exiting Application",
                                MessageBoxButtons.YesNo,
                                MessageBoxIcon.Warning);

            if (res == DialogResult.Yes) {
                aContext.ExitThread();
            }

        }
    }


    class AppContext : ApplicationContext
    {
        //public Form MainForm { get; set; }
        public static ApplicationContext CurrentContext;

        public AppContext(Form mainForm)
            : base(mainForm) {
            CurrentContext = this;
        }
    }
}
```

When the method `OpenMyForm()` is called, I need to assign the application parent form to be able to open the Mid form. Here is the code for this method

public static void OpenMyForm(string sectionName, string[] keys, Form myform) {
        //make sure there are no other forms of the ame type open
        foreach (Form form in Application.OpenForms) {
            if (form.GetType() == myform.GetType()) {
                form.Activate();
                return;
            }
        }

```
    if (Settings._AuthenticationMode == "Thumbprint") {

        var newMDIChild = myform;

        // Set the Parent Form of the Child window.
        newMDIChild.MdiParent = AppContext.CurrentContext.MainForm;

        // Display the new form.
        newMDIChild.Show();
    }


    if (Settings._AuthenticationMode == "Single" && UserInfo.Autherized == true) {

        var role = new Roles();

        if (role.hasAccess(sectionName, keys)) {
            var newMDIChild = myform;

            // Set the Parent Form of the Child window.
            newMDIChild.MdiParent = AppContext.CurrentContext.MainForm;

            // Display the new form.
            newMDIChild.Show();
        }
        else {
            Common.Alert("You do not have a permissions to perform this action!");
        }
    }
}
```

}

When I call the `OpenMyForm()` method from the Main() "Parent" form I get no issues. But When I call it while on an MID form I get the following exception

[image]

```
System.NullReferenceException was unhandled
  HResult=-2147467261
  Message=Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
  Source=Telerik.WinControls.UI
  StackTrace:
       at Telerik.WinControls.UI.RadListElement.HandleMouse(Object sender, RoutedEventArgs args)
       at Telerik.WinControls.UI.RadListElement.OnBubbleEvent(RadElement sender, RoutedEventArgs args)
       at Telerik.WinControls.RadElement.RaiseBubbleEvent(RadElement sender, RoutedEventArgs args)
       at Telerik.WinControls.RadItem.RaiseBubbleEvent(RadElement sender, RoutedEventArgs args)
       at Telerik.WinControls.RadElement.RaiseBubbleEvent(RadElement sender, RoutedEventArgs args)
       at Telerik.WinControls.RadElement.RaiseBubbleEvent(RadElement sender, RoutedEventArgs args)
       at Telerik.WinControls.RadItem.RaiseBubbleEvent(RadElement sender, RoutedEventArgs args)
       at Telerik.WinControls.RadElement.RaiseRoutedEvent(RadElement sender, RoutedEventArgs args)
       at Telerik.WinControls.RadItem.RaiseBubbleEvent(RadElement sender, RoutedEventArgs args)
       at Telerik.WinControls.RadElement.RaiseRoutedEvent(RadElement sender, RoutedEventArgs args)
       at Telerik.WinControls.RadElement.DoMouseUp(MouseEventArgs e)
       at Telerik.WinControls.ComponentInputBehavior.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs e)
       at Telerik.WinControls.RadControl.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs e)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message& m, MouseButtons button, Int32 clicks)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.ScrollableControl.WndProc(Message& m)
       at Telerik.WinControls.RadControl.WndProc(Message& m)
       at Telerik.WinControls.UI.RadPopupControlBase.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
       at System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessageW(MSG& msg)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ComponentManager.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IMsoComponentManager.FPushMessageLoop(IntPtr dwComponentID, Int32 reason, Int32 pvLoopData)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run(ApplicationContext context)
       at RM.Program.Main() in C:\Users\User\C# Projects\RM\RM\Program.cs:line 21
       at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
       at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
       at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
  InnerException:
```

Answer (score 0):

Is there only **one** MdiParent?

If yes, then you could make a little helper class:

```
public class MyApp
{

    public static Form MdiForm
    {
        get {
            foreach (Form frm in Application.OpenForms)
            {
                if (frm.IsMdiContainer)
                    return frm;
            }
            return null;
        }
    }

}
```

Then use it from anywhere:

```
        Form frm = new Form();
        frm.MdiParent = MyApp.MdiForm;
        frm.Show();
```

Answer (score 0):

My code is actually correct. The issue is caused by another code that was causing a close to close unexpectedly.

Answer (score 0):

The application context should be initialized as below,

```
aContext = new AppContext();
```